# Less free space after securely erasing free space?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, disk-space

I use a mid-13 13-inches Retina MBP 256gb with macOS Sierra 10.12.2.

I recently decided to securely erase free space using the following terminal command:

```
diskutil secureErase freespace 1 /Volumes/HD
```

After completing its task, I got 50GB of free space instead of the 80GB I had before the operation.

Could it be a remaining temporary file used by secureErase?

Answer (score 1):

That's it. Do you have external SSD and FileVault enabled? Having SSD drive, `Secure Erase` and `Erasing Free Space` commands aren't needed for SSD drives 'cause a regular erase command makes it difficult to recover data from an SSD.

Also, if you don’t include `freespace` word, `diskutil` will start securely erasing the **entire disk**, instead of just the free space! `1` means single-pass method run of random numbers.

```
diskutil secureErase freespace 1 /Volumes/SSD
```

**Be careful with it**. `Securely erased` means there’s no chance you’ll be able to recover the data.

Read this useful AD post: [Why is a secure erase 'not necessary' for SSD ?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146733/why-is-a-secure-erase-not-necessary-for-ssds)

Comment: The issue is having less space after wiping free space. I think it has something to do with some temp dummy files that haven't been removed properly after secureErase.

Comment: This is considered unsafe. From the man " NOTE: This kind of secure erase is no longer considered safe."