# Secure Erasing Internal SSDs Using File Vault

Tags: filevault, macos, secure-erase

I am the "middleman" in an effort to collect old, unused Apple devices from seniors living in an aging-in-place community.  My intention is to collect their devices, wipe them clean, then donate them to a local charity resettling Afghan refugees in the immediate area.
Erasing HDDs I understand.  Erasing SSDs is where I need guidance.
I suspect all the donated computers will be 2016 or before and most will be laptops.
I read that if I turn on FileVault, encrypt the SSD, boot into Recovery mode and erase the SSD, that will be the equivalent of securely erasing an HHD with one or two passes writing ones and zeros.
Is this correct - I feel a very strong obligation to those donating old computers to get this right.

Answer (score 0):

You describe [cryptographic erasure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306916/5472) well.

Rotating the encryption key ensures data written with that key is unrecoverable. You might go one further by writing legitimate and non-personal data to fill the drive once you encrypt it. Maybe a selection of YouTube videos you downloaded so that all addressable sectors have data overwritten if you can’t be sure FileVault was enabled when the data you hope to make unrecoverable was written.

1. Do an erase install - enable FileVault with a secure, throwaway complex password (like three long words)
2. Copy actual files to fill the drive
3. Repeat the erase install and don’t set up the new Mac

Nothing can go back and re-encrypt spare blocks on the storage (the non-addressable storage part), but these steps ensure any subsequent file recovery returns your actual test files and not the previous owners data had they not encrypted the machine before copying data to it. Only vendor specific drive wipes or physical destruction can cover non-addressable storage being swapped back into service.

To ”get this right” you will want to ensure you let non-T2 era macs complete the FileVault encryption after copying data and before the second erase to ensure all blocks are rewritten. Also, you will need to track the version of macOS used to be sure your efforts are the best possible for each era of hardware.

Comment: Thank you very much for that feedback and confirmation.

Comment: Except that this is not correct. This is not equivalent to securely erasing a HDD with one pass (or even two passes). Cryptographic erasure works ONLY if you encrypt the drive _before_ you add the personal data that you would like to erase later.

Comment: Sure @jksoegaard I’ll elaborate on the edge case of spare blocks - I’m all for people choosing their harm and threat model and being informed.

Comment: Your answer is still incorrect regarding the "spare" blocks - those steps will not ensure that any subsequent recovery do not return the previous owners data. If you do recovery on those "spare" blocks, you might well find the previous owners data. The method you describe wil not "ensure all blocks are rewritten" - it is only the addressable blocks that are rewritten.

Comment: Hard agree, you can’t control the controller. Not sure I can be more clear with addressable and non addressable space. I don’t think everyone needs the same threat model, though.

Comment: Well, perhaps my explanation was more clear - but my problem is not just with the clarity, it is mostly with the facts. You write that "Nothing can go back and re-encrypt spare blocks on the storage", which is not really true - that is exactly what the Secure Erase feature on drives do (when done correctly). "Secure Erase" is not vendor specific, it is a part of the ATA standard (and various others standards such as SCSI, NVMe, etc - for example it is known as Sanitize in NVMe). Your "To get this right" seems to imply that the proposed method will cover the spare blocks - it doesn't.

Comment: OP here. Wow! This has become extremely complicated for me. Might another way to do this be to install Permanent Eraser, <http://www.edenwaith.com/products/permanent%20eraser/> then identify the genuinely critical files on a donee's SSD, erase them, folder by folder,  using that app, and don't worry about the non-critical, non-finance, non-privacy data?

Comment: No @Penny11 - only vendor specific steps can properly purge a drive. You would need to validate the vendor for each and every drive to do this perfectly in every case.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is "almost" correct - but not entirely true.

The idea behind what is here called "cryptographic erasure" is that you encrypt the SSD before using it at all. The key for the encryption is not stored on the drive itself, but elsewhere in a place that allows for secure erasure (on a Mac this is usually in a T1, T2 or M1 chip, but on older Macs this relies on the user having a passphrase that is not easy to brute force). After you have used your computer and filled the drive with personal data, you can effectively erase it all in a safe manner by disposing of the key only.

However this only works in an optimal fashion for the data that is stored *after* the drive is encrypted.

What happens in your scenario is that you have an SSD filled with potentially personal data that is unencrypted. Then you encrypt the drive, overwriting all addressable data with basically random data (that is really just encrypted "nothings") - and then you forget the encryption key used - making those "nothings" unreadable.

You might think that this is the same as overwriting a traditional harddisk with random data - but it is not.

The reason is that SSDs have storage that is not addressable by the operating system. The SSD controller continually swaps blocks in and out of being addressable - which means that some personal data could have been stored in blocks that are now not addressable - and thus not possible to erase by overwriting from the operating system.

If you had encrypted the disk before using it and done a "cryptographic erasure" by erasing the key - this would have worked well, as even the unaddressable data would be un-encryptable as the key is gone. However, in your scenario the unaddressable data is still there.

Note that it is not easy for others to actually get to that un-addressable personal data. It is entirely unlikely that if gifted to for example an average home user that reinstalls macOS and uses the computer in an ordinary manner, would ever see that old data. Things are different though, if the computer is gifted to a computer professional or someone who is willing to spend resources on digging out the old data.

This is why modern SSD drives come with a special command for this particular situation. The command is often referred to as "Secure Erase" or in newer SSDs as "Enhanced Secure Erase". You should be wary though that this particular command has [been shown to be very poorly implemented](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/fast11/tech/full_papers/Wei.pdf) on many consumer SSDs, so you actually need to verify that it is a good implementation before relying on it.

In your scenario you're probably only dealing with Apple-sold SSDs (although you might see computers that have been upgraded by third parties). If this had been a local business here seeking to comply with laws such as the European GDPR, such pre-2016 SSDs would have been assesed to having no or non-functional Secure Erase methods, and would therefore have been physically destructed and replaced with new disks before reuse of the computer. This is not a terrible waste since a 7+ year old SSD is probably nearing the end of its life time anyway.

However, I can understand that in a donation scenario, replacing disks is not possibly. I would recommend that you make it clear to donaters that you do reasonable attempts to clear their drive of personal data by overwriting it (for example 5 passes), while making clear it is not a 100% guarantee of data erasure. Then everyone can make an informed choice.